# Aligning Tooltip (div) to Text (span). Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I am struggling to think of a way in which I can achieve the following, I have thought of it logically and I am pretty sure I cannot do it without javascript (jQuery).

I simply would like to know whether anybody has any clever CSS tricks that will achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Onto the description :-). I am trying to vertically align a `div` to a `span`, where the div may be of different heights dependant on the content. Please see image below to get a better understanding of what I would like to do:

[image]

This is my **starting point** for the code (please forgive minification, just how I type).

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="address" title="no need for this as custom tooltip will replace">Link Text here</a>
    <div class="tooltip"><span>Description of the link here</span></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="address">Link 2 Text here</a>
    <div class="tooltip"><span>Description of the link here</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0 0 0 30px;overflow:visible;}
li {position:relative;border:1px solid #000;margin:5px 0;}
li a {font-size:14px;}

li .tooltip {position:relative;margin-left:100px;width:140px;padding:10px;font-size:12px;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #999;border-radius:4px;z-index:10;}
```

**UPDATE**

Please do not post up any answers regarding the jQuery or javascript (or any css code that shows or hides the tooltip), I can write this myself. I simply want to know whether this can be achieved with CSS. The functionality of the tooltip is irrelevant here, I simply want to hear your opinions/solutions to my aligning issue :-)

Comment: Only with a table or display: table-cell

Comment: @Andy yeah, that is what I feared. I will not be resolving to that. Have already started on the jQuery solution as I cannot see this being solved :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go! http://jsfiddle.net/25UWs/2/

And here is an example that uses CSS3 transitions to show and hide the tooltip http://jsfiddle.net/25UWs/5/

NO javascript used. I also took the liberty to add in tooltip arrows with just css.

The key is to use these css properties (in the proper place of course)

```
display:table;
display: table-cell;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Here's the css from jsfiddle example:

```css
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin: 20px;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:visible;
    display: table;
}

li {
    position:relative;
    margin:5px 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}

li a {
    color: #555;
    font-size:14px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li .tooltip {
    background: #ff;
    width:140px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

/* arrow */
li .tooltip:before,
li .tooltip:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -8px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    content: '';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent; 

    border-right: 8px solid #fff; 
}

li .tooltip:before {
    border-right-color: #999;
    left: -9px;
}
```

​

Comment: Very nice, not sure you need table and table-cell though. This looks fine for me on chrome, at least: http://jsfiddle.net/JH6Ba/

Comment: That is very clever, and seems to be exactly what I was looking for. The only comment I would make, how browser compatible is this? the `:before` and `:after` css selectors are CSS3 (I think) and will therefore not work in the older browsers. As usual, the client wants full browser support (from IE7+) Nightmare!! :-(

Comment: Please ignore last comment! Have looked up the `:before` and `:after` selectors and they are in fact compatible! Very impressed with this answer!! :-D

Comment: If you are worried about the :before and :after selectors, you could easily replace them with images. Besides, if you wanted to get creative with arrows like using gradients, drop-shadow, etc, you would have to use images anyways :)

Comment: Ah, I have just noticed a little problem that complicates this slightly. I will still accept this as the answer as I am very impressed with what you have done, however, what you have done is give a set width to the `a` tag which makes this a lot easier (not easy, just easier) :-)

Comment: @KevinJantzer Just to comment on the gradients and drop shadows etc, I only use CSS to generate these on parts of my sites that look fine without so in old browsers the site looks fine, but in new browsers it looks better. Otherwise, where necessary, I will use images :-)

Comment: You could take the width out and it would still work. But defining the width was the only way to get the link on two lines. Alternatively, you could add <br> to get links to be two or more lines and then you could remove the width on <a>

Comment: @KevinJantzer Yup, you are right :-) The only other problem is that, because the tooltips are positioned relatively, the li sizes to the height of the tooltip. I didnt explain this very well so I do not blame you for making this mistake, my fault! :-) Basically, the tooltip will only be visible when the links are hovered over, and therefore the text will actually be tightly next to each other vertically. Dont think there is anyway around this is there?

Comment: I just posed a second example that does exactly this! http://jsfiddle.net/25UWs/3/

Comment: @KevinJantzer You are a genius! Thank you so much. Just testing on my site :-) Out of interest, is the `display:table-cell` necessary as it seems to work without?

Comment: Good call, doesn't look like display:table-cell is needed (nor the vertical-align). I just updated the example link again: http://jsfiddle.net/25UWs/5/  Now <a> does not have a width and the <li> is not 100% width (so tooltip ONLY shows when hovering over the link text)

Comment: @KevinJantzer does the same apply to the `display:table` on the `ul`?

Comment: Actually, I think they are both needed. Chrome renders it ok, but Firefox does not. http://jsfiddle.net/25UWs/3/ works but vs 4 and 5 do not

Comment: @KevinJantzer All sorted!! Thank you very much for your time, very impressed by this :-D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need at all `display: table-cell`, simply put `display:inline-block` on your `<li>` and position: absolute to your `<div>`.

```
.tooltip {
position:absolute;
right: -10px;
top: -15px; /* or bigger if you need so */
margin-left:100px;
width:140px;
padding:10px;
font-size:12px;
background-color:#fff;
border:1px solid #999;
border-radius:4px;
z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Have tried similar things to this, afraid it is not the solution for several reasons. Firstly, the `div` is not dynamically centered to the text in the span as the `top` margin will differ for each different size tooltip. Secondly, the `li` elements will not flow onto new lines if they have a display of `inline-block` unless I use the `<br>` tags which I like to avoid

Comment: You could do another thing, get rid of your links, place the text into a <p> (it's clickable trough javascript) and place the tooltip div inside it. Now the <p> will have `display: inline-block; position: relative;` and you can even place the tooltip at the middle with top: 50% and margin-top: -[your tooltip height (determined with javascript)]px;

Comment: That solution is still using javascript. It is easy to do using javascript, I wanted to achieve it without but feared I wouldnt succeed. I have now written a javascript (jQuery) solution that I will post once tested. This solution works regardless of what tag the tooltip is in, and regardless of the content size. No need to place it into specific tags